# How to save authenticated username into a database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm just a beginner to `Spring` and `Spring Security`. Here I'm creating a `Spring MVC` application with `Spring Security`. I just want to save authenticated username into a database. Using following form I'm getting the logged username. But I don't know how to save that username using `path=""` attribute.

This is the form

```
<form:form modelAttribute="reservation">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>

        <sec:authentication var="user" property="principal" />
        <sec:authorize  access="isAuthenticated()">
            ${user.username}
        </sec:authorize> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email</label>
        <form:input path="emailAddress"/>
    </div>
```

Here is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/flight-reservation", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String doReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation") FlightReservation reservation ,BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "flight-reservation";
    }
    reservationService.save(reservation);
    return "redirect://flight-reservation.html?ok=true";
}
```

I can save `email` using `path="emailAddress"` But my question is how to save that logged `username` using `path` of something else. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Spring security integration in Spring MVC, you directly get principal as a controller parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/flight-reservation", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String doReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation") FlightReservation reservation,
        BindingResult result, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal){
    // use principal (Authentication.getPrincipal) to extract user name and use it
    ....
```

This one is valid since Spring Security 3.2 If you use an older version, you must use the `SecurityContextHolder`:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Principal principal = authentication == null ? null : authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Assuming that your authentication object returns a `UserDetails`, you could use it that way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/flight-reservation", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String doReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation")
        FlightReservation reservation ,BindingResult result,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails details){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "flight-reservation";
    }
    reservation.setUser(details.getUserName); // adapt it to your real classes...
    reservationService.save(reservation);
    return "redirect://flight-reservation.html?ok=true";
}
```

That mean you use `${user.username}` in the JSP to *display* current authenticated user name, but you get it directly from Spring security in your controller, store it in your `reservation` object that already contains the other fields initialized via the form and pass the object containing th user name (or whatever it contains representing the authenticated user) to the service. That way, Spring security guarantees that the user written in the database **is** the authenticated user even it somenone tries to send a forged request.

---

Alternatively, [Spring Framework Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) explicitely says that you can pass a `Principal` parameter to a `@RequestMapping` annotated method, and the parameter will recieve `the currently authenticated user`. In fact you get `request.getUserPrincipal` that was populated with the Spring Security `Authentication`

So you can simply write:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/flight-reservation", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String doReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation") FlightReservation reservation,
        BindingResult result, Principal principal){
    Authentication auth = (Authentication) principal;
```

or directly as `Authentication` implements `Principal`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/flight-reservation", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String doReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation") FlightReservation reservation,
        BindingResult result, Authentication auth){
```

and get the user name from there.

Comment: Thanks for the mention @serge , but I'm using Spring Security 4.0.1 and Spring 4.1.6. It is working that getting logged username using `${user.username}` May I know is there anyway to pass that value to the database ?

Comment: @sarge I tried as you said. I set `@AuthenticationPrincipal User user`, User is my entity for users. Then I set `reservation.setName(user.getName());` But after running this code and when I check user table, it is saving a null for `name`. Am I correct according to above corrections ?

Comment: Insted of using `@AuthenticationPrincipal` I've used `Authentication`. It works well and save the name into the database. Is it correct ? If it is correct please edit your answer then I can mark your answer as the answer for my question. Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations. All doubts are resolved.